# Windows 7 Professional Upgrade to Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I want to upgrade Windows 7 Professional to Windows 8 Pro keeping all my softwares and files intact. Can I upgrade? I am not sure whether Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate users can upgrade to Windows 8 Pro keeping their softwares/apps and files intact.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the option of keeping programs, system settings and files when upgrading from 7 to 8. See the table *Transferring settings, apps, and files* at MS' site below for the official line.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8

Vista machines can keep system settings and files, XP machines just files, and 7 machines system settings, applications and files, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I assume when i upgrade by browser settings - bookmarks, history, downloads history, sessions etc would also be saved